# ElasticSearch rest high level client createIndexRequest

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

Iam trying to create an index using the rest high-level client by passing the indexName as
"test_".
But the request that goes to the ElasticSearch has "test_%5C" as the indexName.
Why is ElasticSearch appending %5C instead of .

CreateIndexRequest req = new CreateIndexRequest("test_")